# Amazon MWS- continue to get signature mismatch error even though the signature matches scratchpad (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-mws

I am trying to send a POST request to the /Finances endpoint and cannot get past the error that says:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Finances/2015-05-01">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I have taken the parameters right off of successful queries on Scratchpad and run them through my hashing process and am calculating signatures that match those calculated on Scratchpad so I know my signature process is accurate but even in those instances, I am still receiving the mismatched Signature error. This tells me that maybe there is something else wrong with my request, however I've tried many different variations and mimicked the documentation with no success.

I've tried ordering my parameters in ASCII alphabetical as well as in the order that scratchpad shows (which is not alphabetical) and neither works. There are no typos in any of my keys or extra spaces. I am lost on what could be causing this and would really appreciate some help if you've worked with mws. Below is my code:

```
const method = "POST";
const hostName = "mws.amazonservices.com";
const requestUri = "/Finances/2015-05-01";
const keyId = XXXXXXXXXXXX;
const action = "ListFinancialEvents";
const authToken = XXXXXXXXXx;
const sellerId = XXXXXXXXX;
const secretKey = XXXXXXXXXXXx;
const signatureVersion = "2";
const timestamp = new Date();
const formattedTimestamp = timestamp.toISOString();
const version = "2015-05-01";
const signatureMethod = "HmacSHA256";
const postedAfter = "2020-06-07T0:00:00Z";

const queryString =
  "AWSAccessKeyId=" +
  encodeURIComponent(keyId) +
  "&Action=" +
  encodeURIComponent(action) +
  "&MWSAuthToken=" +
  encodeURIComponent(authToken) +
  "&PostedAfter=" +
  encodeURIComponent(postedAfter) +
  "&SellerId=" +
  encodeURIComponent(sellerId) +
  "&SignatureMethod=" +
  encodeURIComponent(signatureMethod) +
  "&SignatureVersion=" +
  encodeURIComponent(signatureVersion) +
  "&Timestamp=" +
  encodeURIComponent(formattedTimestamp) +
  "&Version=" +
  encodeURIComponent(version);

const stringToSign =
  method + "\n" + hostName + "\n" + requestUri + "\n" + queryString;

const signature = crypto
  .createHmac("sha256", secretKey)
  .update(stringToSign)
  .digest("base64");

const queryBody = querystring.stringify({
  AWSAccessKeyId: keyId,
  Action: action,
  MWSAuthToken: authToken,
  PostedAfter: postedAfter,
  SellerId: sellerId,
  SignatureMethod: signatureMethod,
  SignatureVersion: signatureVersion,
  Timestamp: formattedTimestamp,
  Version: version,
  Signature: signature,
});

const options = {
  hostname: hostName,
  path: requestUri,
  method: method,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length": queryBody.length,
    Host: "mws.amazonservices.com",
    "User-Agent": "myMWSApp/1.0 (Language=Javascript)",
  },
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log("statusCode", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers:", res.headers);

  res.on("data", (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on("error", (e) => {
  console.error("ERROR:", e);
});

req.write(queryBody);
req.end();
```